# Filter list view with url parameter. Strange behavior in Internet Explorer (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, filter, internet-explorer

I have a link opening the listview AllItems.aspx with specific filter parameter in the url which works fine.
But if the user tries to change the filter of the prefiltered column, e.g. by selecting "Include Descendants" or "Clear Filters from [ColumnName]" I get a strange behavior in Internet Explorer.

While it works in Firefox and the url parameters get changed, in Internet Explorer a set of (strange encoded) parameters will be added **after** the initial url paramters.
The added paramters beginning with `#InplviewHash` will not be processed by the borwser and for the user nothing changes.

### Example

#### Firefox

**Initial URL**:

`/Lists/Articles/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Topics&FilterValue1=232&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterData1=0%2C10da0eac-592c-4025-adf6-809c14811432`

**After selecting "Include Descendants"**:

`/Lists/Articles/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Topics&FilterValue1=232%2C86&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterData1=1%2C10da0eac-592c-4025-adf6-809c14811432&View={07B3C7B1-6A96-4007-A165-EACED7E8C3AC}`

#### Internet Explorer

**Initial URL**:

`/Lists/Articles/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Topics&FilterValue1=232&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterData1=0%2C10da0eac-592c-4025-adf6-809c14811432`

**After selecting "Include Descendants"**:

`/Lists/Articles/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Topics&FilterValue1=232&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterData1=0%2C10da0eac-592c-4025-adf6-809c14811432#InplviewHash07b3c7b1-6a96-4007-a165-eaced7e8c3ac=CascDelWarnMessage%3D1-FilterField1%3DTopics-FilterValue1%3D232-FilterLookupId1%3D1-FilterOp1%3DIn-FilterData1%3D0%2C10da0eac--592c--4025--adf6--809c14811432`

Does anyone have experiences with this behavior and knows how to solve it.
Seems like this happens only in Internet Explorer, but I didn't test it in Chrome.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Ruslan Dayanov's hint I have now the answer for this case.

Predefined filter parameter in the url **should not set** as valid query string parameter like `AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Topics&...` because they **will not be replaced** while filtering via AJAX and always have a **higher priority than the filter parameter, which are set by SharePoint logic and appended with "#"** in url.

While the parameter after "?" remain the same, inplview.aspx will always return a result based on these parameter and ignores other parameters after "#"

**Solution:**

Based on the given URL examples, the **initial url** shoud be:

`/Lists/Articles/AllItems.aspx#InplviewHash07b3c7b1-6a96-4007-a165-eaced7e8c3ac=CascDelWarnMessage%3D1-FilterField1%3DTopics-FilterValue1%3D232-FilterOp1%3DIn-FilterLookupId1%3D1-FilterData1%3D0%2C10da0eac--592c--4025--adf6--809c14811432`

Answer (score 4):

The new page added in layouts folder "inplview.aspx". When paging, sorting or filtering happens there is an AJAX call to the inplview.aspx and it returns a JSON based result set. That is the rows of the defined list view webpart. The "inplview.aspx" generates the "inplviewhash" tag and appends it with "#" in url.

Comment: Thanks! With your hint I could solve the problem. While Firefox simply makes a post request and the whole page is reloaded, IE uses the inplview.aspx. In my case, the filter parameter in the url after "?" always overwrote the filter parameter set by SharePoint after "#", so inplview.aspx always returned the same result. If I open the page with only # parameters in the url, changing filters works in both browser.

Answer (score 1):

This blog will explain the how inplview parameter works in [SharePoint 2013 Custom List View Web Part Refresh](http://roykimsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/sharepoint-2013-custom-list-view-web-part-refresh/)