# FilterOp1 Not Working

Tags: url, filter

In SP 2010, we could filter a list view through the query string by using FilterField1, FilterValue1 and FilterOp1, where FilterOp1 could be an operation like Eq and Neq. However, in SP 2013, I cannot get FilterOp1 to work, that is, regardless of the value I pass, it always assumes Eq.

What has changed? Is it possible to get the old functionality?

Comment: It is supported as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filterfieldqueryoperator(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Here is another thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114992/filter-list-view-with-url-parameter-strange-behavior-in-internet-explorer-shar

Comment: Amal: the first link is about ContentByQueryWebPart, which is not related to my question. As for the second one, I have seen it - I can Google myself - but it isn't accurate or misses something because it doesn't work on two different servers.

Comment: Apparently, it works in document libraries, but not on lists, while on SP 2010 it worked in both.

Comment: I tried this `CustomList/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=ghxg&FilterValue1=2&FilterOp1=Gt` on my custom list and it worked

Comment: Very weird, doesn't work in mine... what edition of SP 2013 are you using?

Comment: I tried in SharePoint Online and On-Premise Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to understand what the problem is.

Comment: It does work perfectly in a new list, but not in existing ones... I suspect it's because they have been customized (added/removed columns). Will investigate further.